# Can one specify an alternate location for secrets.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to specify a path for `secrets.yml` other than the default `config/secrets.yml` that is relative to the Rails root directory?

Comment: Which rails version?

Comment: @RAJ I guess it would have to be 4.1 or greater?  (That's when secrets.yml was introduced, I think.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to override `secrets` method in `config/application.rb`:

```
def secrets #:nodoc:
  @secrets ||= begin
    secrets = ActiveSupport::OrderedOptions.new
    yaml = config.paths["PATH_TO_SECRET_YAML_FILE"].first

    if File.exist?(yaml)
      require "erb"
      all_secrets = YAML.load(ERB.new(IO.read(yaml)).result) || {}
      env_secrets = all_secrets[Rails.env]
      secrets.merge!(env_secrets.symbolize_keys) if env_secrets
    end

    # Fallback to config.secret_key_base if secrets.secret_key_base isn't set
    secrets.secret_key_base ||= config.secret_key_base

    secrets
  end
end
```